# Does every function with $f_x,f_y>0,f_{xx},f_{yy}<0$ with particular condition have to satisfy $f_{xy}/f_{xx} = -x/y$?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let continuous real functions $f$ of two real variables $x,y$ satisfy the following condition:

(Let us define $f_{xx}:=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ and $f_x:=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, and $f_{xy}:=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}$)

\begin{equation}
f_x > 0,\\
f_{xx} < 0,\\
f_y > 0 ,\\
f_{yy} <0,\\
f(\lambda x, \lambda y) = \lambda f(x,y)
\end{equation}
for all $\lambda > 0 $, and $$\lim_{x \to 0}f_x = +\infty, \lim_{x \to +\infty}f_x = 0, \lim_{y \to 0}f_y = +\infty, \lim_{y \to +\infty}f_y = 0.$$

If the aforementioned condition is satisfied, how can we show or disprove that for every function that satisfies the aforementioned condition,
$$\frac{f_{xy}}{f_{xx}} = -\frac{x}{y}?$$

If we are disprove the case, what would be the counter-example?

Comment: Should this be posted at mathoverflow?

Comment: When you say $\infty$, it is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$?

Comment: It is $+\infty$.

Comment: No, this should definitively not be posted at mathoverflow. Your condition $f(\lambda x, \lambda y)=\lambda f(x,y)$ forces the derivative in x-direction along the x-axis to be constant, so that you limes conditions cannot be satisfied everywhere. So of course nobody can give a counterexample, because there is no example at all to satisfy these conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You should totally drop all those sign conditions. Just having the *degree-one homogeneity* $$f(\lambda x,\lambda y)=\lambda f(x,y)$$ is enough. Indeed, let $g(x,y)=f_x(x,y)$. Using the chain rule, you can check that $g$ is *degree-zero homogeneous*: that is, $$g(\lambda x,\lambda y)= g(x,y)$$ (This is an instance of a more general fact: taking the derivative drops the degree of homogeneity by one.) Since $g$ is constant on every halfline emanating feyly from the origin, it follows that 
$$\nabla g(x,y) \cdot (x,y) = 0$$
which in terms of $f$ is $$xf_{xx}+yf_{xy}=0$$